# In spark SQL char() function returns only ASCII characters but i need UNICODE characters also

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

if the given argument is above 256 it converted into n % 256
How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

char/chr doesn't support that but maybe you van use java method that does it:

```
SELECT java_method('java.lang.Character', 'getNumericValue', 'Ͱ')
```